# Only getting parent tag name, not child on click event using prop("tagName"). Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the tags name when I click on them, I have applied a common class on each tag. Now the proplem is when ever I click on p tag or h1 it always gives the parent name.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.r').click(function(event) {
    // $('.r').each(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $detect = $('.r').prop('tagName');
    // alert($detect);
    console.log($detect);
  });
  // })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">
 <h1 class="r">Title H1</h1>
 <p class="r">Para</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `var $detect = $(event.target).prop('tagName');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.r')` will always give you the first-element.

So

***Either Use `$(this)`:-***

```js
$(function(){
  $('.r').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $detect = $(this).prop('tagName');//$(this) will give you current clicked object
    console.log($detect);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">
  <h1 class="r">Title H1</h1>
  <p class="r">Para</p>
</div>
```

***Or You can use `$(event.target)` also:-***

```js
$(function(){
  $('.r').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $detect = $(event.target).prop('tagName');
    console.log($detect);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">
  <h1 class="r">Title H1</h1>
  <p class="r">Para</p>
</div>
```

`event.target` will give the current element on which event perfom actually.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` instead of `$('.r')`-

```js
$(function() {
  $('.r').click(function(event) {

    // $('.r').each(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $detect = $(this).prop('tagName');
    // alert($detect);
    console.log($detect);
  });
  // })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">
  <h1 class="r">Title H1</h1>
  <p class="r">Para</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `var $detect = $('.r').prop('tagName');` to `var $detect = $(this).prop('tagName');` and you will get it.

When you use the selector `$('.r')`, by default, you are working with the first element of the returned array(`<div class="r">`).

```js
$(function() {
  $('.r').click(function(event) {
    // $('.r').each(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $detect = $(this).prop('tagName');
    // alert($detect);
    console.log($detect);
  });
  // })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r">
  <h1 class="r">Title H1</h1>
  <p class="r">Para</p>
</div>
```